# Epicor ERP Physcial server

Tags: server, erp, epicor

I am going to integration my Epicor system to wordpress site.

I mean I am going to integration database of Epicor to wordpress's database.

By the way, my Epicor system is located on physical server of my company. In this case, do i have to upload my local server to online server?

For get data from Epicor to wordpress, do I have to make online server of Epicor?

Let me know please. thank you

Answer (score 0):

if one server is online and the other is offline
yes you will need them both to be online servers if you require real time integration without manual procedures .

To make your company server online , you will need to get static public IP from your internet provider and configure it on your server to access it online.

What you need to do for uploading data to WordPress site by making connection to database from your WordPress website to your Epicor server .

and please adjust the question its very confusing but hopefully I answered what you need if I got you right

Comment: thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am going to clear my questions. Yeah so I have to integration wordpress database and Epicor ERP. So my customers can see their order status, payment processing etc on wordpress site, for this I have to send data of Epicor ERP's data to Wordpress.

Comment: you will need to make connection string which read data from your epicor server .

Comment: By the way our company have local physical server as Epicor server. Yeah I  understand what you mean. So I have to get static public IP address from my internet provider.

Comment: yes when you get the  public IP , configure it on your server and your epicor server will be online , then you can configure connection string database to your server to read data from wordpress to your server\

Comment: I am first on this Epicor department, so could you explain more about this?  "To make your company server online , you will need to get static public IP from your internet provider and configure it on your server to access it online."

Comment: when you purchase public ip from your isp the ip will look like x.x.x.x with subnet x.x.x.x and gateway as well as dns , this you will have to configure it on your network server adapter , after that your server will be online , you could enable IIS server and visit your server as http://x.x.x.x and your server will be accessible .

Comment: Epicor support team said me "If you're on Epicor 10, you could probably have the wordpress site talk to the Epicor DB via the REST API, but that would require you to expose the appserver publicly and would of course introduce security concerns."  Do you know about this? If you know, could you explain more about this? In this case do i have to change my physical server to online server?

Comment: What is epicor database type ? - Yeah Epicor's database is sql database.

Comment: you can do it then , all you have to do is to make it online

Comment: give me your email I can help you to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your question is, "How do I get data from on-premise Epicor ERP for use in WordPress"?

You do not have to upload anything. Epicor has a very good API. One thing the comments here leave out, however, is that it's very dangerous to simply take your on-premise server and expose it to the internet. You should use SSL and a non-standard port, and protect yourself with a limited access scope via an API key.

So here are the steps (do everything in a DEV environment first obviously) and each one is a mini-project in its own right (for which Google is your friend).

1. Get your static IP for the location where your on-premise server lives;
2. Select a port to open (EG 8989) that is not standard;
3. Use router port forwarding to connect that WAN port to your Epicor AppServer;
4. Get an SSL certificate set up for connecting to your system from the WAN;
5. Create an integration user in Epicor (EG username WPConnect) and make this a basic authentication user;
6. Create an API key in Epicor that gives access only to the data you want to access in WordPress;
7. Test your connection using the integration user in the browser (Google "Accessing Epicor Rest API in Swagger") from a computer that is NOT on the same network as your server;
8. Make sure your Epicor AppServer is set up for Token authentication;
9. Use PostMan to figure out your REST API calls, starting with generating your token;
10. On the WordPress side work out your http calls to use the API